# linkerd: auto injection ignored

Tags: linkerd

I've installed linkerd correctly (linkerd check --proxy -n linkerd checkings are all ok).

After that, I've annotated my `covid` namespace with `"auto-injection"`:

```
$ kubectl annotate namespace covid linkerd.io/inject=enabled
```

After having deployed my deployment:

```
$ linkerd stat deployments -n covid
NAME                MESHED   SUCCESS   RPS   LATENCY_P50   LATENCY_P95   LATENCY_P99   TCP_CONN
dev-covid-backend      0/1         -     -             -             -             -          -

$ linkerd stat pods -n covid
NAME                                 STATUS   MESHED   SUCCESS   RPS   LATENCY_P50   LATENCY_P95   LATENCY_P99   TCP_CONN
dev-covid-backend-7ccc987d4-494lv   Running      0/1         -     -             -             -             -          -
```

As you can see, deployment is not meshed.

I've trigerred heartbeat manually. I'm getting:

```
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=info msg="running version stable-2.7.1"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=error msg="Prometheus query failed: unexpected result Prometheus result vector length: 0"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:39Z" level=info msg="Sending heartbeat: https://versioncheck.linkerd.io/version.json?install-time=1588663782&k8s-version=v1.17.3%2Bk3s1&meshed-pods=9&p99-handle-us=50000&source=heartbeat&total-rps=3&uuid=991db911-da8b-45c7-98b5-eb63e6162e8d&version=stable-2.7.1"
time="2020-05-05T12:29:43Z" level=fatal msg="Failed to send heartbeat: Check URL [https://versioncheck.linkerd.io/version.json?install-time=1588663782&k8s-version=v1.17.3%2Bk3s1&meshed-pods=9&p99-handle-us=50000&source=heartbeat&total-rps=3&uuid=991db911-da8b-45c7-98b5-eb63e6162e8d&version=stable-2.7.1] request failed with: Get https://versioncheck.linkerd.io/version.json?install-time=1588663782&k8s-version=v1.17.3%2Bk3s1&meshed-pods=9&p99-handle-us=50000&source=heartbeat&total-rps=3&uuid=991db911-da8b-45c7-98b5-eb63e6162e8d&version=stable-2.7.1: dial tcp: lookup versioncheck.linkerd.io on 10.43.0.10:53: server misbehaving"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the `dev-covid-backend` deployment after annotating the `covid` namespace?

```
kubectl rollout restart deploy/dev-covid-backend -n covid
```

The heartbeat check is unrelated to the auto injection feature. You can check the `proxy-injector` logs

```
kubectl logs -f deploy/linkerd-proxy-injector -n linkerd
```

as well as the events:

```
kubectl get events -n covid
```

If you see errors or messages there, they should help to find a resolution.